# Is it possible to use @JsonInclude NON_DEFAULT without a zero-argument constructor?

Tags: java, json, jackson

if I have a POJO without zero-argument constructor:

```
class POJO {
    int a;
    int b = 5;
    int c = 6;
    int d = 7;

    POJO(int a) {
        this.a = a;
}
```

I would like to serialize the non-default values by using `@JsonInclude(value = NON_DEFAULT)`. In the above case serialize `b` only if it's not 5, `c` only if it's not 6 etc. I understand the issue with `a` which is why a non-default constructor is needed and would like to resolve it by always serializing `a` so that deserialization can invoke this constructor and then for the rest substitute non-default values only.

I tried `@JsonCreator` on the constructor but it has no effect. How can I serialize only non-default with non-zero constructor?